# Master-Slave and Publish-Subscribe connections

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

Assuming I have a Master-Slave deployment of Redis (1 master, 1 slave) and a client (webapp) that will manage Publish-Subscribe.

- Can I Publish messages to the slave and will they be "seen" by the master?
- Or should I use only the Master for Publish and the Slave for Subscribe commands?

I've been looking around but couldn't find the answer. Anyone knows?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the typical data you store in Redis, you should only write to the master.

From http://redis.io/topics/replication:

> ...writes [to slaves] will be discarded if the slave and the master will [sic] resynchronize, or if the slave is restarted...

In fact, starting from v2.6, you can put slaves in `slave-read-only` mode which would prevent the mistake of writing data to a slave.

The documentation does go on to mention a potential use case for writing data to slaves:

> ...often there is ephemeral data that is unimportant that can be stored
>   into slaves. For instance clients may take information about
>   reachability of master in the slave instance to coordinate a fail over
>   strategy.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As @jameshfisher pointed out, the link below is regarding `Redis Cluster`. The comment from @lionello seems to be the correct answer:

> Publishing to a slave will not propagate to the master, only the other way around.

The answer is on the *[cluster-spec](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec)* docs:

> **Publish/Subscribe**
>
> In a Redis Cluster clients can subscribe to every node, and can also publish to every other node. The cluster will make sure that published messages are forwarded as needed.
> The current implementation will simply broadcast each published message to all other nodes, but at some point this will be optimized either using Bloom filters or other algorithms.

Comment: In a regular primary-replica setup in AWS, I could not get messages published on the replica to show up on a client subscribed to the primary, but the other way around worked: subscribe on replica, publish on primary.

Comment: Redis Cluster is different to Redis master/slave.

Comment: Right! Updated the answer.

Comment: The "Bloom filter" qualification is gone in the current version of the docs.  Now it simply states: _In a Redis Cluster, clients can subscribe to every node, and can also publish to every other node. The cluster will make sure that published messages are forwarded as needed._